# Media content downloaded from text message can't be found

Tags: htc-8x

I have an HTC for WP8 with version 3.9 software.  Recently, I've been having occasional problems with downloading media from text messages.  When I click the link to download the media content it doesn't show on my screen (normal) or appear in my photo files. I'm not getting any error message telling me I can't download it.  How can I find the files or determine if they are somewhere on the phone?  If they didn't download is there an error file that I can look at?

Thanks for responses!

Comment: What network are you on? Have you checked your APN settings are correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have had a similar problem, first make sure your phone is getting the text message through your cellular network and not over wifi, you likely are not able to recieve messages over wifi, next go to settings, cellular, and select "data connection" and on. You may also need to check "data roaming options" depending on if your  carrier is in your area and limited Wi-Fi connectivity option in case your phone is defaulting to the Wi-Fi and refusing to use cellular. Make sure phone is not doing Wi-Fi calling either.

If this does not work contact your carrier's help number and see if your phone ask them to guide you in making sure your phone is properly set up to work on their network.